# Google Glass: open menu on touch in regular Card

Tags: android, menu, google-glass, google-gdk

How do I have the menu pop up on a regular `Card`. I have tried to use this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
          openOptionsMenu();
          return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Also, is it possible to put `Live Cards` in an `Activity` like I did here. I believe I am using `Static Cards`, but eventually I will need access to the camera and video functions through these Cards.

**Activity**

```
public class NewChecklistActivity extends Activity {

private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
private List<Card> mCards;
private CardScrollView mCardScrollView;
StepCardScrollAdapter adapter;

Intent checklistIntent;
String allStepsJSONString;
ArrayList<String[]> allStepsArray;
ArrayList<String[]> checklistsArray;
ArrayList<String[]> stepsArray;
ArrayList<String[]> checklistSteps;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    checklistsArray = (ArrayList<String[]>) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("checklists");
    stepsArray = (ArrayList<String[]>) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("steps");

    createCards();
    mCardScrollView = new CardScrollView(this);
    adapter = new StepCardScrollAdapter();
    mCardScrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mCardScrollView.activate();
    setContentView(mCardScrollView);
    mCardScrollView.setOnItemClickListener(adapter);
    checklistIntent = new Intent(this, ChecklistActivity.class);
}

private void createCards() {
    mCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    Card card;
    String[] checklist;

    for (int i = 0; i < checklistsArray.size(); i++) {
        checklist = checklistsArray.get(i);
        card = new Card(this);
        card.setText(checklist[1]);
        mCards.add(card);
    }
}

private class StepCardScrollAdapter extends CardScrollAdapter implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public int findIdPosition(Object id) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public int findItemPosition(Object item) {
        return mCards.indexOf(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mCards.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mCards.get(position).toView();
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        checklistIntent.putExtra("steps", getChecklistSteps(adapter.findItemPosition(position)));
        startActivity(checklistIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: this line if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) responds to every touch, I mean even swipe down, back and forward including tap..so if you want this to only work for a tap and nothing else (like swipe down, forward and backward) I guess its better to use GestureDetector class ...see here https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/touch

Comment: +1 for a giving me a new insight on this event !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you're using a `CardScrollView`, which is going to intercept all of the touchpad gestures and that's why your `onKeyDown` method isn't getting called.

For this specific case, you can attach an `OnItemClickListener` to the card scroller and use that listener to find out when one of the cards is tapped. Then, call `openOptionsMenu` from there.

If you need to have different menu items for different cards, you'll need to store the index of the card that gets passed into the listener and then use that information inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu` to load different items. The flow would look like this:

1. You create a private field in your activity class that will store the index of the last tapped card.
2. In your `onItemClick` method, you store the index you're given in that field, and then you call `openOptionsMenu`.
3. This causes `onPrepareOptionsMenu` to be called. Override that method and do whatever modifications you need to the menu based on the index stored in that field (inflate a menu, add/remove items, etc.). You have to do this inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu` instead of `onCreateOptionsMenu` because you want it to happen *every* time the user taps, not just the first time the menu is initialized.
4. Handle `onOptionsItemSelected` as you normally would.

Comment: Working great now. I added my working code above. Thanks for the help and info that `CardScrollView` intercepts all the touchpad gestures.

Comment: Got a question in terms of having the `onItemClickLister` get the right item. I am trying to pass in an `ArrayList` that contains items that pertain to which Card was clicked. How do I go about storing the index of the card that gets passed to the listener? I added the code for the `CardScrollAdapter` above. Thanks!

Comment: It would probably be better to have the activity implement the listener (or implement it in a separate inner class) rather than having the adapter implement it (just from a software design point of view). I'm editing my answer above to clarify the process of storing the index.

Comment: I just implemented the listener in the `onCreate` attached to the `CardScrollView`. Thanks for the help!